# Data mapping column to row

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert

I have a table name `CodeStatement` with schema

```
Name            Null? Type         
--------------- ----- ------------ 
CODE                  VARCHAR2(7)  
STATEMENT_DESC1       VARCHAR2(20) 
STATEMENT_DESC2       VARCHAR2(20) 
STATEMENT_DESC3       VARCHAR2(20) 
STATEMENT_DESC4       VARCHAR2(20)
```

and I have another table `CodeSequence` with schema

```
Name        Null? Type         
----------- ----- ------------ 
CODE              VARCHAR2(7)  
SEQ               NUMBER       
DESCRIPTION       VARCHAR2(20)
```

`SEQ` column holds the value from 1 to 4 which represent the `STATEMENT_DESC` columns in `CodeStatement` table.

Here I am trying to map description from `CodeSequence` column to `CodeStatement` column
for specific code based on the value of `SEQ` column.

For example if entry in `CodeSequence` is

[image]

Then value inserted in `CodeStatement` should be

[image]

My approach is as follows:

```
insert into CodeStatement
select case when seq = 1 then (select code,description as Statement_Desc1,null as Statement_Desc2,null as Statement_Desc3,null as Statement_Desc4 from CodeSequence )
    when seq = 2 then (select code,null as Statement_Desc1 ,description as Statement_Desc2 ,null as Statement_Desc3 ,null as Statement_Desc4 from CodeSequence )
    when seq = 3 then (select code,null as Statement_Desc1,null as Statement_Desc2,description as Statement_Desc3,null as Statement_Desc4 from CodeSequence )
    when seq = 4 then (select code,null as Statement_Desc1,null as Statement_Desc2,null as Statement_Desc3,description as Statement_Desc4 from CodeSequence )
    end
from CodeSequence ;
```

But it is giving me error as "too many values".

Answer (score 2):

Error you got is due to subqueries returning more than a single row.

The way you put it, conditional aggregation might do the job:

```
SQL> insert into CodeStatement (code, statement_desc1, statement_desc2, statement_desc3, statement_desc4)
  2  select
  3    code,
  4    max(case when seq = 1 then description end) desc1,
  5    max(case when seq = 2 then description end) desc2,
  6    max(case when seq = 3 then description end) desc3,
  7    max(case when seq = 4 then description end) desc4
  8  from codesequence
  9  group by code;

2 rows created.

SQL> select * from codestatement;

CODE    STATEMENT_DESC1      STATEMENT_DESC2      STATEMENT_DESC3      STATEMENT_DESC4
------- -------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
EP                           this is amazing
AMS     hi this is nice                           this is good

SQL>
```